# Get Values from my Service to my Page in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

Right now I managed to get the DB-Data from my PHP-API. Now I'm struggling to send it from my service to my `page.ts`. Somehow it keeps being undefined.

Service:

```php
getData(dbargument:String) {

 var headers = {
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 };

  let fullheader = new HttpHeaders( headers );
  let postData = dbargument;
  let postDataJson = JSON.stringify(postData);
  let header = new HttpHeaders();

  let real_header : any = header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  this.http_post.post('URL is set here', postDataJson, real_header).subscribe(data => {

     console.log("JSONSTRING: " + JSON.stringify(data));

     return data;
 });

}
```

Page.ts:

```php
ngOnInit() {

    /* Calling Data on Page load */

    this.platform.ready().then(() => { 
    this.getActiveJobs();

    console.log('Post initialized');

    });

}

getActiveJobs() {

    this.activeJobsID = this.activeJobs.userid;
    this.activeJobsStr = "//Working SQL Statement is here";
    this.activeJobsCount = this.activeJobs.getData(this.activeJobsStr);

    console.log('Post worked');
    console.log(this.activeJobsID);
}
```

The Variable I'm trying to get the value in is `activeJobsCount`.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Current Problem  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nG2I.png)

Edit 2:

It looks the problem lies in the following part :

```
this.http_post.post('http://kfz-expertus-portal.de/API/dbpost.php', postDataJson, real_header).subscribe(result => {

  console.log("JSONSTRING: " + result);

  return result;

});


the JSONSTRING is shown in the logs but i cant return the result to the page.ts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it. I just had to return the http-response at once without saving it in result and return it then.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not returning data from service.

```
getData(dbargument:String) {

 let tmp;

 var headers = {
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 };

  let fullheader = new HttpHeaders( headers );

  let postData = dbargument;

  let postDataJson = JSON.stringify(postData);


  let header = new HttpHeaders();

  let real_header : any = header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  this.http_post.post('URL is set here', postDataJson, real_header).subscribe(data => {

  console.log("JSONSTRING: " + JSON.stringify(data));

  this.temp = data;

});

return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you at first! i changed it to your code, while changing "this.temp=data" to to tmp = data. i think you meant tmp and "this." shouldnt be necessary, because this is no instance right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, delete 'this' from the code. I hope it works.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt. it looks like the returning tmp has no value;

Comment: Is console.log("JSONSTRING: " + JSON.stringify(data)) printing anything?

Comment: Also it's better to use subscribe in your page like @tomas-vancoillie suggested

Comment: Yes its printing what you can see in my edit. Its the right value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't **wait** for the data, the `getData` function goes from top to bottom in an instant and returns `undefined` as it should. You will need to wait for the http post to return and then send it to your page.

```js
getData(dbargument:String): Observable<any> {
  // ... other
  return this.http_post.post('URL is set here', postDataJson, real_header);
}
```

Call the function from your service and see the result as you subscribe to the getData Observable

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.getActiveJobs();
}

getActiveJobs() {
  this.yourservice.getData(data).subscribe(result => {
    // result here
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you! :) I did it and got the following error: core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined. Im looking for a solution right now

Comment: Is your http_post variable, the injected HttpClient?

Comment: Yes, constructor is the following: ```constructor(private http_post: HttpClient) { }```

Comment: Just found out that ``` this.activeJobs.getData(this.activeJobsStr) ``` is undefined

Comment: You should check whether you receive any data back from the POST. Does your php api send data back? You can check this with postman if you like (https://www.getpostman.com/)

Comment: I can see the correct value in chrome developer tools in the network-tab which should mean that i get the correct value back

Comment: I linked the current error in my Edit in my question. The value u see there (14) is the right one retrieved from the api.

Comment: i think the prob lies in one specific part =>  edit 2

Comment: @Nhean Good, you have the data. Do you use the observable way to access that data in your page.ts?

Comment: Hello, i fixed it. I just had to return the http-response at once without saving in in result and return it then. Thanks for you help :)